# Require entered password to have a capital letter and a number?

Tags: java, android, validation, passwords

I have a working registration on my application and the following code is a small part of that. As you can see there are a bunch of requirements to validate the password/username.

Three of them are similar and do not work. Those are the three strings: upperCaseChars, lowerCaseChars and numbers. I tried to make it so that the password has to contain a uppercase letter, a lowercase letter and a number before it calls the 'insertToDatabase'.

I have searched all over the internet and could not find what I was looking for. P.S: I want to add it in a similar fashion as the other requirements in the if statement.  Any way to do this?

```
 public void invokeRegister(View view) {
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
        String pass = editTextPass.getText().toString();
        String pass2 = editTextPass2.getText().toString();
        String upperCaseChars = "(.*[A-Z].*)";
        String lowerCaseChars = "(.*[a-z].*)";
        String numbers = "(.*[0-9].*)";

        if (name.length() >= 4 && name.length() <= 12 && (pass.length() >= 6 && pass.length() <= 18 && (pass2.length() >= 0 && (pass.equals(pass2)) && pass.contains(upperCaseChars) ))) {
            insertToDatabase(name, pass);
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `String.matches` as `String.contains` doesn't use a regex?

Comment: Do you really want a maximum password length of 18?

Comment: Still in the testing phase. You reckon 18 is too long?

Comment: If you want safer passwords, the longer the better. May be 100 is a reasonable limit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 99% of people's passwords are no longer than 18. I could up it a bit, but 100 seems a little overkill!

Comment: True, but why place a limit at all other than to protect yourself from really crazy inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for the presence of an uppercase letter is easier than you'd think. Convert the entire String to lowercase and see if it matches the original string.

Example:

```
String pass = "password" 
if( !pass.equals(pass.toLowerCase()) ) //fails

String pass = "passWord";
//lower casing becomes "password" and as a result, "passWord" doesn't match "password"
if( !pass.equals(pass.toLowerCase()) ) //passes
```

And perform the opposite to check for a lower case letter:

```
if( !pass.equals(pass.toUpperCase()) )
```

Next for your criteria to ensure the password contains a number, try this:

```
String pass = "pa55w0rd";
if( pass.matches(".*\\d+.*") ) //passes
```

Click [here](https://regex101.com/r/kA6fA9/2) to see how this regex works.

---

The conditions combined:

```
if( !pass.equals(pass.toLowerCase()) && 
    !pass.equals(pass.toUpperCase()) && 
    pass.matches(".*\\d+.*") 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up now won't work because it's looking for the entire string of letters (A through Z) in the password. What you can do is create your own method that will return true if three booleans become true (ex: hasCapital, hasLowercase, hasNumeral). I'd recommend using an array of chars and then comparing each char in the password string to each char in an array of the valid characters for each condition.

Keep in mind, there are likely far better solutions than this one.. But it will work.